# Integrate R with VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, r, random, statistics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to communicate with R through VBnet( or C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10763516/how-to-communicate-with-r-through-vbnet-or-c)

I want to generate a random number from log-normal and triangular distribution in VB.NET.

To do so I thought of integrating R with VB.NET. I added following reference to R,

```
STATCONNECTORCLNTLib;
StatConnectorCommonLib;
STATCONNECTORSRVLib;
```

My questions:

1. is there anything else that I need to do to use R in VB.NET
2. How can I use R commands in VB.NET?

Thanks!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5377070/c-sharp-r-interface, and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10763516/how-to-communicate-with-r-through-vbnet-or-c, and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10763516/how-to-communicate-with-r-through-vbnet-or-c and more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Using R from .NET

You can find an example on how to use R from .NET here:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25819/The-R-Statistical-Language-and-C-NET-Foundations

It is written for C#, but I think it's easy to translate to VB.NET.

The most important thing seems to be initalizing which is done by:

```
Dim sc1 As New StatConnectorSRVLib.StatConnectorClass()
sc1.Init("R")
```

After this you can use the `sc1` object to evaluate symbols etc.

### Alternative: Random number generator library for .NET

However if I may make a suggestion. Why not use a random number library for .NET like this one?

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15102/NET-random-number-generators-and-distributions

It contains both log-normal and triangular distribution, so it should fit your need and you don't need to have R installed. It will probably faster also because it's a native .NET library.